# passing a variable it to su command in bash script

Tags: bash, variables, sudo

I need to issue a command from a e.g. root to user zimbra. The problem is that I also need to set an env variable and some other variables.

From a command line I do it like this (that's command used for creating a mailbox in Zimbra):

```
su - zimbra -c 'export LC_ALL=nb_NO.UTF-8 && p="user.name" && domain="@example.com" && displayname="User Name" && givenname="User" && /opt/zimbra/bin/zmprov ca $p$domain "" cn "$displayname" displayName "$displayname" givenName "$givenname" zimbraPrefFromDisplay "$displayname"'
```

It works fine. The problem occurs when I try to automate the process in bash script. I can't (or don't know how to) pass a variable generated inside script to su command.

```
#!/bin/bash
var="something";
su - zimbra -c 'export LC_ALL=nb_NO.UTF-8 && echo $var'
```

When I use script above it doesn't work because $var is declared for root user, not for zimbra user. Is there a way to to baypass this?

I've tried to bypass this by generating a string first:

```
#!/bin/bash
var="something";
string="'export LC_ALL=nb_NO.UTF-8 && echo $var'";
su - zimbra -c $string
```

but when I do this I get

LC_ALL=nb_NO.UTF-8: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
LC_ALL=nb_NO.UTF-8: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Any help?

Comment: Two things I have noticed. 1. Your `$var` is inside single quotes. So it won't be interpreted. 2. May be you need to enclose the variables inside the double quotes. Like : `su - zimbra -c "$string"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202383/how-to-pass-environment-variable-to-sudo-su

Comment: I've seen this, but that's no this. I need to change only one env, not preserve all from root user. Also that's for env and I need to pass vars

Comment: Basically my problem is that:

    su - zimbra -c 'echo $PATH'

is not the same as:

    string="'echo $PATH'" && echo $string && su - zimbra -c $string

Comment: And here's the answear (depending on what you want to achieve):
    string="echo $HOME" && sudo -H -u zimbra bash -c "$string"
    string="echo \$HOME" && sudo -H -u zimbra bash -c "$string"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately none of the above comments ideas worked for me. I wound up puzzling out that I could do the following. Escaping the double-quotes and wrapping in actual double-quotes seems absolutely necessary, plus pipe to xargs allowed the realized variable to be passed through.

`echo "\"/web/jboss-eap-7.1/bin/domain.sh -Djboss.domain.base.dir=$NODE/\ &\"" |  xargs su - jboss -c`

Hope this answer helps others!

Comment: nice idea but it doesn't work when su ask a password... any ideas ?